# angular 4 custom theme

Tags: angular, angular-material2, custom-theme

I'm new to angular 4 and Angular material.Currently I'm using angular 4 and trying to create a custom theme. When creating the custom-theme.scss file,  we are using variables to assign colors to primary, accent and warn like follows,

```
$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-orange);
$my-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-white);
$my-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
```

I'm bit confused about this `mat-palette($mat-light-orange);`, because I can't understand the way it assigns variables to primary, accent and warn colors. What is the meaning of `mat-palette` and how can we assign custom colors to this?

This is the code I used in custom-theme.scss, but it's not working.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
$mat-light-orange:#fbab4a;
$mat-white:#ffffff;
$mat-red:#e95337;
$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-orange);
$my-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-white);
$my-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent, $my-app-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($my-app-theme);
```

Comment: Are you using Angular CLI? If so, have you included `custom-theme.scss` in the `styles` array property of `angular-cli.json`? If not, have you compiled this scss file to css and included it in `index.html` or similar?

Comment: Yes I'm using Angular CLI and it's already included in the angular-cli.json file as below,                                                                                    
       "styles": [
            "styles.scss",
            "custom-theme.scss"
        ],                                                                                                                              But still not working

Comment: Okay, that means that the values such as `$mat-light-orange` you are passing to the `mat-pallete()` sass @function are not valid. There are predefined palette variables in the Angular Material source files. Please see my answer for further information.

Comment: Yes, That was the problem. Thanks. Now It's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), you'd need to include this file in the `styles` array property of the file `.angular-cli.json` to ensure the build process includes this custom theme in your application.

```
...
"tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
"testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
"prefix": "app",
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "custom-theme.scss"
],
"scripts": [],
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
...
```

If you are NOT using Angular CLI, you'd need to use some sort of build process or at minimum a tool such as `node-sass` to compile the SCSS to CSS. Once compiled, you need to link to the file in something like `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Foobar</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <link href="path/to/compiled/assets/custom-theme.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Just creating the SCSS file will likely NOT be enough. It depends on the build process you are using to detect and process assets such as SCSS style files.

In regards to the SCSS variables for colors such as `$mat-indigo`, these be found in `_palette.scss` within the [source](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/dccce1cdac8a1755d743de65a295bb5cfc2799b1/src/lib/core/theming/_palette.scss) and tie to the colors of [Material Design Colors](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette). These variables can be used within your custom theme SCSS file as needed for your design. So the color you are trying to reference `$mat-light-orange`, isn't a valid/existing palette/ and may not come out as you expect. You'd instead target the existing palettes such as `$mat-orange` and use the optional parameters to target specific hues such as `A200` which comes out to color code `#FF9100`. `mat-pallete()` and `mat-light-theme()`  are custom Sass @functions in the Angular Material [source](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/7f65f31ef84c6713ee7f0cf4a7148a7f69d5d713/src/lib/core/theming/_theming.scss) that take inputs such as the color palettes and generate/compiles the theme CSS.

`$my-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-orange, A200);`

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks, It's working. I think there was a problem when assigning colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the theme in your `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    "custom-theme.scss"
]
```

Alternatively you can import it in your global `styles.scss` file:

```
@import 'custom-theme.scss';
```

---

**What is the meaning of mat-palette**

`mat-palette` is a mix-in that generates the color palette for your application. It generates colors for texts, backgrounds etc. that are needed for the material components. All you have to do is to insert some [material colors](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette) as arguments to the mix-in:

```
$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 800, 300, 900);
$app-accent: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
$app-warn: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange, A200);
```

The numbers behind the color variable (e.g. $mat-indigo, 800, 300, 900) specify the default, lighter and darker contrast of your color palette.

[image: color palette]

I hope this helps you!